Countable set meeting uncountable family of positive measure sets
Suppose $\mu:\mathcal{P}([0, 1]) \to [0.1]$ is a probability measure and $\{A_i: i < \omega_1\}$ is a family of subsets of $[0, 1]$ such that $\mu(A_i) \geq 1/2$ for every $i < \omega_1$. Can we find a countable $A \subseteq [0, 1]$ such that $A \cap A_i \neq \emptyset$ for every $i < \omega_1$?

The answer to your question is consistently no, for any (countably additive) probability measure on $[0,1]$. If we restrict ourselves to a standard Borel measure, then the answer is also consistently yes, so in this case the answer to your question is independent of ZFC.
On the one hand, the Continuum Hypothesis (CH) implies the answer is no for any probability measure. If CH holds, then you have an enumeration of $[0,1]$ in order type $\omega_1$: i.e., $[0,1] = \{ x_i : i < \omega_1 \}$. Now let $A_i = \{ x_j : i < j \}$. Each of these sets is co-countable, hence of measure $1$, but no countable set meets them all.
On the other hand, Martin's Axiom at $\aleph_1$, $MA_{\aleph_1}$, implies the answer is yes for standard Borel measures. If $\mathbb P$ denotes the forcing poset to add one random real, then consider the (finite support) countable power $\mathbb P^\omega$, which adds countably many random reals. It's not too hard to check that for any given $A_i$, the set of all conditions forcing one of your generic reals is in $A_i$ is dense in $\mathbb P^\omega$. Consequently, $MA_{\aleph_1}$ implies we have a generic on $\mathbb P^\omega$ that meets all $\aleph_1$ of these dense sets simultaneously; i.e., we have a countable sequence of reals, and each of your $A_i$ contains at least one of them.
(For the record, I think that using $\mathbb P^\omega$ is a nice way to think of things in the MA proof. But you could just use $\mathbb P$ itself if you prefer, since adding a random real to $\mathbb R$ also adds one to $[0,1]^\omega$.)
This argument doesn't work for more general measures, because in that context the forcing poset to add a "random" member of $[0,1]$ may not be ccc, which means $MA_{\aleph_1}$ does not apply. The other answer posted here indicates that this version of the question may be much harder.

$\text{MA}_{\omega_1}$.

Are you assuming the measure is Lebesgue measure?

@EmilJeřábek: I was assuming a standard Borel measure. But, looking again at the question, perhaps I shouldn't be?

Since there's another answer which, as far as I understand, concerns the general case, perhaps you could add your assumption at the beginning of the answer. I think this answer is interesting in its own right.

@AlessandroDellaCorte: I agree -- done.

Short answer: Your question is most likely open and (to the best of my knowledge) has been originally posed by Fremlin (555Z(b) in his Measure theory Vol. 5 here).
Without loss of generality, we can assume that $\mu$ vanishes on singletons since the set of such singletons is at most countable. So, in the nontrivial situation, we can assume that, $|[0, 1]| = \mathfrak{c}$ admits a diffused probability measure and it is well-known that this implies that MA/CH fails and that the continuum is above a weakly Mahlo etc.
The standard model (due to Solovay, Real valued measurable cardinals, 1971) for this is obtained by starting with a measurable cardinal $\kappa$ and adding $\geq \kappa$ random reals. The witnessing measure obtained in this model does satisfy the conclusion of your question. In fact all total measures do. For details see here.
